# Logic breakdown - unexpected behavior testing value

Tags: java, android, logic

I've got a function which looks in android assets and loads if asset exists.
If Not then looks on file system. If it finds it, it loads it - if file not zero bytes.
If not found on file system it makes 2 attempts to get it from a server. 
All of this works except if the the file is already there and the size is 0 - and its failing on some "primitive" java logic test. I can't see what is wrong here and exploring the possibility of it being a bug outside of my own code.

The problem is occurring at

```
if (lenoffile>1){  // always fails
```

where any check of this int against 0 causes the function to return and not execute the expected flow.

```
private String readQuestions(String xml_file){
    Log.i(TAG2,"readQuestions");
    List<String> mapList = null;
    String xmlString = null;
    int lenoffile =0;
    AssetManager am = this.getAssets();
    try {
        mapList = Arrays.asList(am.list(""));
        if (mapList.contains(xml_file)){
            InputStream is = am.open(xml_file);
            int length = is.available();
            byte[] data = new byte[length];
            is.read(data);
            xmlString = new String(data);
            return xmlString;
        } 
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        Log.i(TAG,"Failed in ReadQuestions() from assets");
    //  e1.printStackTrace();
        //return null;
    }
    Log.i(TAG2,"File not an asset. Must be on FS");
    if (me.FileExists(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + APPDIR +"/"+xml_file)) 
        xmlString = m.fileLoader(xml_file);

    if (xmlString != null){
        lenoffile = xmlString.length();
        Log.i(TAG2,"Length of file found=" + lenoffile);
        if (lenoffile>1){ // below never gets executed even with lenoffile==0
            Log.i(TAG2,"Returning here with a file of length "+ lenoffile);
            return xmlString; // assume the full file exists and validate
        }
    }   // if else then there is a null situation
    else{   // look on FS and load accordingly          
            DownloadFileAsync Z = new DownloadFileAsync();
```

trace:

```
06-09 12:26:58.197: I/SRCFILE(11792): readQuestions
06-09 12:27:08.822: I/SRCFILE(11792): File not an asset. Must be on FS
06-09 12:27:15.197: I/SRCFILE(11792): Length of file found=0
```

Thanks in advance.

Kevin